# Javascript Get Sequential Dates in Array cross week and month

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have an array with the following values (example):

```
[
  1491408000000,
  1491494400000,
  1491753600000,
  1493222400000,
  1493308800000,
  1493568000000
]
```

Where the index is a date time. The date time will always be at 12:00:00 on a date.

In this example, the first 3 dates are consecutive cross weekend (weekend is holiday so count as leave), then another group of 3 dates cross weekend and month.

Now, what I am trying to do is find sequential dates (cross week and month) and put them into an array as follows:

```
[
  1491408000000,
  1491494400000,
  1491753600000
],
[
  1493222400000,
  1493308800000,
  1493568000000
]
```

I have tried the following code to get the sequential dates but this cannot cross week and month, how to modify the code to get above result? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var timeValue = new Date(dateReview).getTime(); 
valueCon.push(timeValue);                                           

var k = 0;   
sortedValue[k] = [];

valueCon.sort( function ( a, b ){
    return +a > +b ? 1 : +a == +b ? 0: -1;
})
.forEach( function( v , i ){
    var a = v,b = valueCon[i+1]||0;

    sortedValue[k].push( +a );

    if ( (+b - +a) > 86400000) {                                
        sortedValue[++k] = []
    }
    return 1;
});                     

sortedValue.sort( function ( a,b ){
    return a.length > b.length ? -1: 1;
});
```

Comment: If 1491408000000 is a time value, then it's equivalent to 2017-04-05T16:00:00.000Z, which is only noon where the time zone offset is -04:00. Are you just trying to group them by month?

Comment: No, I want to group cross week like the example:
2017-04-06, 2017-04-07, 2017-04-10 --> one group (since 2017-04-08, 2017-04-09 are Saturday and Sunday)

2017-04-27, 2017-04-28, 2017-05-01 --> one group (same resaon and cross next month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires help from a function to test if two dates are in the same week. The following goes over the set of time values provided in an array and puts the first value into an array within the array. For each subsequent value, it tests if it's in the same week as the first value in each array within the outer array.

If it's in the same week as the first value in any existing array, it's pushed into that array. Otherwise, it's put in a new array and pushed into the outer array.

There may be a neater way to implement the algorithm, but I'll leave that for others.

Due to time zone differences, they are adjusted to the host time zone based on the original time values representing noon in the source time zone.

```js
// Given 2 dates, return true if they are in the same week (Mon to Sun).
// Otherwise, return false
function sameWeek(a, b){
  var e = new Date(+a);
  // Week starts at 00:00:00.000 on Monday on or before date
  var s = new Date(e.setDate(e.getDate() - ((e.getDay()||7) -1)));
  s.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  // Week ends at 23:59:59.999 the following Sunday 
  e.setDate(e.getDate() + 6);
  e.setHours(23,59,59,999);
  // Test b and return value
  return b >= s && b <= e;
}

// Given time value for UTC-0400, adjust to same date and time
// in local time zone and return a date
function adjust(n) {
  var d = new Date(n);
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 240 + d.getTimezoneOffset());
  return d;
}

var result = [1491408000000,1491494400000,1491753600000,1493222400000,1493308800000,1493568000000
].reduce(function(acc, n) {
  var d = adjust(n);
  var used;
  if (acc.length != 0) {
    used = acc.some(function(arr) {
      if (sameWeek(adjust(arr[0]), d)) {
        arr.push(n);
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
  if (!used || acc.length == 0) {
    acc.push([n]);
  }
  return acc;
},[]);

// Result array
console.log(result);

// Printed as date strings adjusted to same host local time
result.forEach(arr => {
  arr.forEach(n => console.log(adjust(n).toString()))
  console.log('\n');
});
```

Comment: That's what I wanted, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Manipulation of timestamps is a pain. JavaScript has a built-in `Date` type, as you know, and I would suggest you use it. `Date#getUTCDay` returns the day of the week as an integer (for reference, `4` is Friday, or the day before a weekend), while `Date#setUTCDate` and `Date#getUTCDate` together allow you to adjust the date in day increments (and have it overflow/underflow to the next/previous month). Thus, to determine whether a timestamp `b` follows "sequentially" (excluding weekends) after `a`, you can use:

```
function sequential (a, b) {
  a = new Date(a)
  return a.setUTCDate(a.getUTCDate() + (a.getUTCDay() === 4 ? 3 : 1)) === b
}
```

Grouping is just an exercise after that; the code above contains all of the real logic behind this solution.

---

### Example Snippet

```js
var dates = [
  1491408000000,
  1491494400000,
  1491753600000,
  1493222400000,
  1493308800000,
  1493568000000
]

function sequential (a, b) {
  a = new Date(a)
  return a.setUTCDate(a.getUTCDate() + (a.getUTCDay() === 4 ? 3 : 1)) === b
}

function groupSequential(dates) {
  if (dates.length < 2) return [dates.slice()]
  dates.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b })
  
  var result = [], group
  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    sequential(dates[i - 1], dates[i]) || result.push(group = [])
    group.push(dates[i])
  }
  return result
}

console.log(groupSequential(dates))
```

Comment: Please explain? It appears to work well on my end, how is it failing on yours?

Comment: cannot seperate into 2 groups, just seperate one by one

Comment: So you want to be able to access each group one at a time, is that what you're saying? You can use array methods for that, or just array indexes / a for-loop. For example, `var groups = groupSequential(dates); console.log(groups[0]); console.log(groups[1])`.

Comment: output: 
[
  [
    1491408000000
  ],
  [
    1491494400000
  ],
  [
    1491753600000
  ],
  [
    1493222400000
  ],
  [
    1493308800000
  ],
  [
    1493568000000
  ]
]

output I wanted:
[
  1491408000000,
  1491494400000,
  1491753600000
],
[
  1493222400000,
  1493308800000,
  1493568000000
]

Comment: I am getting the output you wanted on my end. Maybe it's a browser implementation issue? What timezone are you in and what browser are you using?

Comment: hone kong and chrome

Comment: Is this when running my example snippet above (on this page), or when you move the code to your own script?

Comment: Both are the same